# Can I specify a "root" folder for a user?

Tags: spotfire, spotfire-webplayer

I am wondering if there is a way how I can set a root folder for a user. For example, I have the following folder hierarchy in the Spotfire library:

```
/ (root)
   DNA
     UserFolder
       User_123
       User_234
```

Can I use specify what would be the root folder for a user to be "User_123" - the user won't be able to go up the tree using the WebPlayer but only inside their own folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no capability for a feature like this.

in Spotfire 10 there is a feature called "[Sites](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/spotfire_server/10.0.0/doc/html/TIB_sfire_server_tsas_admin_help/GUID-EC9DEFE0-C31F-48DF-8E13-11D8E4856E2D.html)" which effectively creates unique libraries per server joined in a cluster, but I don't think it's feasible to create one server per user, and currently I understand there are some issues with clusters containing more than four servers [citation needed]. but the feature is interesting and new so, there you have it.

what I would recommend instead is to get creative with your [library permissions](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/spotfire/6.5.0/doc/html/lib/lib_permissions.htm) (doc is for version 6.5 but these have not changed). in your example:

- / `B+A` for Everyone group (this is required)
- DNA `B+A` or `Inherit` for Everyone group (otherwise nobody will be able to see it)
- UserFolder `B+A` or `Inherit`
- User_xxx do not `Inherit`, `B+A+M` for that specific user

the effect will be that all users can navigate up to the User_xxx level, but will only be able to see folders to which they have `A` permissions.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, it won't be feasible to create one server per user but thank you for the suggestion. The main reason behind my question was to be able to force the user to stay in their folder and not go up the tree. So they will be able to create folders down starting from their folder (essential root for them). But it also helps to know that this is not, currently, possible. Thank you a lot! :)

Comment: the good news is that with `B+A` permission, they will only be able to see, not create or modify. I frequently see structures like `/org/dep/team/user` with less restrictive permissions the deeper you get. the most important part is to have a person/team who is/are the assigned library administrator(s). any library can quickly sprawl out and get crazy with no oversight.

Comment: Yes, that is a good way to set up the file hierarchy. I think my team can stick to something similar in order to get as close to solving the above problem. Thank you for your answer. Much appreciated :)